# How to parse a command output in bash

Tags: bash

I am executing a command on bash which gives me the following output

```
bash-4.2$ soapcli.sh maxadmin "my_passw0rd" "http://localhost:8777/ws/pid/TpmLiteSoapService?wsdl" executeDeploymentRequest testCleanup "numeber=1234"
Result: 990823
```

How to store the Result i.e. is 990823 in a variable. I stored the entire output in a variable using:

```
res=`soapcli.sh maxadmin "my_password" "http://localhost:8777/ws/pid/TpmLiteSoapService?wsdl" executeDeploymentRequest testCleanup "number=1234" 2>&1

echo $res
Result: 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `awk` command through the pipe `| awk {print $2}` into your command:

`bash-4.2$ soapcli.sh maxadmin "my_passw0rd" "http://localhost:8777/ws/pid/TpmLiteSoapService?wsdl" executeDeploymentRequest testCleanup "numeber=1234" | awk '{print $2}'`